# Exact Target Triggered Send using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

How can we send a transactional email to more than one recipients using FUEL REST Services.
Using the below structure i am able to send mails to a single recipient. Whats the Json structure to send a mail to more than one recipient.

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/dfa5ab87-1b0f-e211-b71b-9c8e9920e9fc/send?access_token=...
Content-Type: application/json
{
"From": {
    "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
    "Name": "Code@"
},
"To": {
    "Address": "example@example.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
    "ContactAttributes": {
        "SubscriberAttributes": {
            "Region": "West",
            "City": "Indianapolis",
            "State": "IN"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you get that working or not, and mark the question answered if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `sendBatch` method.  Let me know if this works for you.

```
messageDefinitionSends/dfa5ab87-1b0f-e211-b71b-9c8e9920e9fc/sendBatch


[
   {
      "From":{
         "Address":"code@exacttarget.com",
         "Name":"Code@"
      },
      "To":{
         "Address":"example1@example.com",
         "SubscriberKey":"example1@example.com",
         "ContactAttributes":{
            "SubscriberAttributes":{
               "Region":"West",
               "City":"Indianapolis",
               "State":"IN"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "From":{
         "Address":"code@exacttarget.com",
         "Name":"Code@"
      },
      "To":{
         "Address":"example2@example.com",
         "SubscriberKey":"example2@example.com",
         "ContactAttributes":{
            "SubscriberAttributes":{
               "Region":"East",
               "City":"Columbus",
               "State":"OH"
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I Tried with the above structure it  work for me. can i know if we can send cc or bcc using REST. will be very helpfull if you can send us the documentation link for this. Thanks Kelly

Comment: Go ahead and mark this answered,  and start a new question for the cc but item.  Thanks!